# plotting a histogram with rCharts?

Tags: r, rcharts

I'm trying to create a histogram with rCharts. This is my code:

```
Age <- structure(list(AGE_FBS001_002 = structure(1:58, .Label = c("14", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", 
"71", "76"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(1L, 4L, 8L, 19L, 35L, 
38L, 65L, 103L, 124L, 128L, 125L, 128L, 135L, 102L, 74L, 117L, 
80L, 68L, 76L, 68L, 70L, 47L, 48L, 42L, 52L, 53L, 34L, 42L, 42L, 
41L, 33L, 24L, 19L, 23L, 29L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 28L, 22L, 18L, 18L, 
13L, 10L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
1L)), .Names = c("AGE_FBS001_002", "Freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
-58L), class = "data.frame")

rp1 <- rPlot(x="bin(AGE_FBS001_002,10", y="Freq", data=data, type="bar")
rp1$params$width <- 700
rp1$params$height <- 500
rp1$xAxis(axisLabel = "Age")
rp1$yAxis(axisLabel = "Count", width = 50)
```

I get this error: "‘xAxis’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “Polycharts”"

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hesitate to put this in as an answer rather than a comment, but here it how we could accomplish in `dimple` with `rCharts`.  There are lots of options for formatting, etc. if you choose to go this route.

```
  library(rCharts)
  library(dplyr)

  Age %>%
    mutate( age = cut(as.numeric(as.character(Age[,1])),seq(0,100,10)) ) %>%
    group_by( age ) %>%
    summarize( Freq = sum(Freq) ) %>%
  # pipe in our transformed data to dimple
  dPlot(
    Freq~age
    ,data = .
    ,type = "bar"
    ,xAxis = list(orderRule = "age")
    ,barGap = 0
  )
```

Comment: I have a few question. What is the difference between dPlot and rPlot? Where can I read about the formatting options you mention? Is it possible to make a histogram instead of a bar graph? (no space between bars) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it in Polycharts.

```
rp1 <- rPlot(x = "bin(AGE_FBS001_002, 10)", y = "Freq", data = Age, type = "bar")
rp1$guides(
  x = list(title = 'Age'),
  y = list(title = 'Count')
)
rp1$set(width = 700, height = 500)
rp1
```

Comment: Thanks! One question: This is a bar graph, there is space between the bars. Is it possible to remove that space so it looks more like a histogram? Is is possible to change the text that pop-outs when the mouse hover the bar? For example, the first bar should be [10-20]

Comment: yes, experimental to set barGap 0 as shown in my demo use `devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/rCharts@dimple_v2.0.0` but note this is experimental.  would think in production in next month or so